Geometric interpretation of a Grammian-like function
Let $\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the following function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:
$$
f(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}) = \|\mathbf{v}\|\|\mathbf{w}\| - |\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{w}|.
$$

Question: Is there a (reasonably natural/simple) geometric interpretation of $f$?

I'll note that $f$ is not the Grammian of $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ (i.e., $\sqrt{\|\mathbf{v}\|^2\|\mathbf{w}\|^2 - |\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{w}|^2}$), which measures the area of the parallelogram with sides $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$. However, I still suspect that there might be a reasonable geometric interpretation of $f$ (as an area, for example), since $f$ has the following nice properties that all somehow seem "area-ish" to me:

By Cauchy-Schwarz, $f(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}) \geq 0$. Furthermore, $f(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}) = 0$ if and only if $\{\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$ is linearly dependent.
$f$ is unitarily-invariant: for all real unitary (i.e., orthogonal) matrices $U \in M_n$ we have $f(U\mathbf{v},U\mathbf{w}) = f(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})$.
$f$ is non-increasing under orthogonal projections: if $P \in M_n$ is an orthogonal projection then $f(P\mathbf{v},P\mathbf{w}) \leq f(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})$.

In fact, I could imagine defining a "$p$-area" of the parallelogram with sides $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ (similar to how we define $p$-norms for $p \neq 2$ to generalize the notion of length) via
$$
f_p(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}) = \sqrt[p]{\|\mathbf{v}\|^p\|\mathbf{w}\|^p - |\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{w}|^p}.
$$
This reduces to the Grammian when $p = 2$, and to the function $f$ that I'm most interested in when $p = 1$. Is this a thing that has been looked at? Any answers or references are appreciated.

How do you prove the 3rd property?

@IosifPinelis - It's a bit long. By unitary invariance (the second property) it suffices to prove the 3rd property for diagonal orthogonal projections (i.e., diagonal matrices with entries from ${0,1}$). In other words, it suffices to prove that the inequality holds if the projection just replaces some entries of $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ by $0$; a fact that is much more concrete to prove (but a bit longer than I want to write in a comment or add to the question).

The 0-1 reduction is of course clear. I don't immediately see what to do after that, though. I thought knowing the proof might help to answer your question, especially if the proof is geometric. If it is rather long, you might want to consider adding a link to it.

The proof seems pretty "plug and chug" to me, but can perhaps be interpreted geometrically. Here is the proof in the case when $P$ zeros out just one entry (the first entry, WLOG). Let $\mathbf{x} = (v_2,\ldots,v_n)$ and define $\mathbf{y}$ similarly from $\mathbf{w}$. Then using C-S on the vectors $(v_1, |\mathbf{x}|)$ and $(w_1,|\mathbf{y}|)$ gives $v_1w_1 + |\mathbf{x}||\mathbf{y}| \leq |\mathbf{v}||\mathbf{w}|$. Subtracing $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}$ from both sides and re-arranging gives exactly $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) \leq f(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})$, as desired.

Nice use of the C-S inequality. I think here you wanted to use $|v_1|$ and $|w_1|$, though, instead of $v_1$ and $w_1$.

Note that $f_1(\vec x, \vec y) = \lVert \vec x\rVert \lVert \vec y\rVert (1 -
|S_C(\vec x, \vec y)|)$, where $S_C$ is the cosine similarity. This is used quite a bit within machine learning, though I don't know if there is anything particularly "interesting" or "geometric" about it. People mostly care that it is fast to compute for sparse vectors, and scale-invariant.

$\sqrt f$ equals $\sqrt 2$ times the area of a parallelogram with sides $\sqrt v$ and $\sqrt w$ and enclosed angle equal to $1/2$ the angle between $v$ and $w$.

@CarloBeenakker - Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you write it up as an answer, I'll gladly accept. (Thank you to other commenters too.)

$\sqrt f$  equals $\sqrt 2$ times the area of a parallelogram with sides $|v|^{1/2}$ and $|w|^{1/2}$ and enclosed angle equal to $1/2$ the angle $\theta$ between $$ and $$.

